# Itext7 Border Overflow With SolidBorder Class

Tags: c#, .net-core, itext, border, itext7

We use ITEXT7 and we encounter a problem, when we create a table with a cell and inside that cell a paragraph the border is nice by default, but when we use the `SetBorder` method with `new SolidBorder(1f)`, we can see that the border isn't clean.

```
new Cell().Add(new Paragraph("test")).SetBorder(new SolidBorder(1f))
```

VS

```
new Cell().Add(new Paragraph("test"))
```

Here an image to show the difference:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for C#, but I am using this in Java right now and the cells have a border by default, unless you specify them otherwise.
I would try omitting the `SetBorder(new SolidBorder(1f))` part first and testing how that works out.
Also, your question is quite minimal as information, maybe you are doing some other manipulation that is interfering with the border drawing mechanism?